# How to find a sobject used in which apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, sobject

How to find which object is used in which apex class or trigger.Ex I want to find apex classes where account object is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Metadata Dependency Query, as outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm). They provide an example in the docs:

```
SELECT MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType
    FROM MetadataComponentDependency
    WHERE RefMetadataComponentId = yourFieldId
```

You can use the Tooling API checkbox in the Query Editor tab of the Developer Console found in Salesforce, or another tool capable of calling the Tooling API.